# Select Option - cannot get selected option

Tags: javascript, html, qunit, selectedindex

I think there is something wrong with my Select/Options tag... I cannot access the selected option.

Here's the HTML part:

```
<select id="filter">
    <option value="value1" selected="selected" data-path="property1">option1</option>
    <option value="value2" data-path="property2">option2</option>
</select>
```

I tried this way:

```
var property_filter = document.getElementById('filter');
```

And while debugging, on the console, this is what I tried:

```
input:  property_filter.options
output:  [<option value=​"value1" selected=​"selected" data-path=​"property1">​option1</option>​,<option value=​"value2" data-path=​"property2">​option2​</option>​]
```

So it's grabbing the right select tag... But something is still wrong:

```
input:  property_filter.selectedIndex
output:  -1
```

Similary, when I used JQuery selector to find this, I'm not getting what I want.

```
input:  $('#filter').find('option')
output:  [<option value=​"value1" selected=​"selected" data-path=​"property1">​option1​</option>​, <option value=​"value2" data-path=​"property2">​option2​</option>​]

input:  $('#filter').find('option:selected')
output:  []
```

I must be doing something wrong... It's such a simple task, too. I also tried using 'selected', not 'selected="selected"' but I got the same result.

I'm using Chrome on OS 10.6.8 by the way, and under context of Backbone View & QUnit test (but it shouldn't matter, right?). Also, this code works outside of QUnit.

Comment: In JavaScript its `selectedIndex`, in jQuery it's `:selected`.

Comment: try .hasAttribute("selected"); to check if its being set, perhaps you are modifying it elsewhere

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mqefD/1/ looks good to me.

Comment: In response to RyanS's comment, this is what I get when I try it with each of the options: 
> property_filter.options[0].hasAttribute('selected')
< true
> property_filter.options[1].hasAttribute('selected')
< false

Comment: @JiMun Given option 2 isn't selected, that makes sense.

Comment: @Daedalus: ANd so I am not sure why what I tried above (selectedIndex, or .find('option:selected')) is not working in this case.

Comment: @JiMun I don't suppose a link to your website where you are testing this, would be possible?

Comment: Sorry.. the site is not publicly available.

Comment: Can't reproduce ( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8H64f/) ). Are you sure it's not because `property_filter !== Property_filter`

Comment: That was typo here... I'll fix that - but it doesn't work for property_filter, either. Those are the outputs for property_filter, not Property_filter

Comment: I'd suggest mkaing a fiddle demonstrating your problem.

Comment: The *selected* attribute has no value, it's a [boolean attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#boolean-attributes). So you can use either "selected" or "selected='selected'", but the second seems verbose.

Comment: I can only reproduce this problem under QUnit.

Comment: That suggests either your test introduces a bug or the QUnit framework does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah... Sorry. I found out why things were not working. And like Peter Wilkinson said, it was a bug that I introduced.

Before I try to get the index, I set the index to 2, (noob mistake!!) which set the index to out of bound index. That's why I kept getting -1 as index.

There was nothing wrong with JQuery or selectedIndex or any of the methods that I tried + I should have debugged further up.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
console.log($(this).find('#filter option:selected'));
```